# PHP Debugging: How to view image resource information

Tags: php, debugging, image-processing

I am debugging a PHP application that handles image resources. I would like to see the output (`$dst_image` as per [the PHP manual's jargon](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)), but the code is not in a place that I could simply output it to the browser. Would the best debugging procedure be to write `$dst_image` to a file, and to load that file in the browser? Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you output to a browser? An `echo` anywhere should do that.

Comment: I cannot output to a browser as other code has already output text to a browser. The image-handling bit happens in the background. If the application used output buffering I could do it, but also it cannto be refactored as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Example #1 and #2](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php), [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) will output the jpeg data.

You need to do few tings:

1. set headers for image `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`
2. output your image data
3. Make sure you are not outputting any data except the image

At the end you should end up with something like this:

```
<?php

// Get new dimensions
// Resample
// etc...

// set header so browser can render image properly
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output
imagejpeg($image, null, xxx);
// [or] 
echo file_get_contents($pathToJpgImage);
```

---

If you find your self in a situation where current request outputs data and you cannot output image... You can inject the base64 encoded image data into the HTML by using `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,..." />`. See [php documentation on base64_encode for images](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#99842).

Comment: Thank you, but for technical reasons (output already sent) the image cannot be simple sent to the browser unless there is a way to negate all the text previously output.

Comment: Although I doesn't address the issue that I bring up, I am accepting this as the accepted answer as it is the canonical solution for the general case. When this solution doesn't work, then one must write the image to a file, as I had suspected. Thank you Alex.

Comment: @dotancohen my apologies, it was not clear to me from your question... See 2nd part of my answer, it should do the trick.

Comment: Alex, that is terrific! It is exactly the fix that I needed but was afraid would not exist! That is a clever and creative solution, I would call it witty if one could describe code as such. Thank you!